# ImageView disapears when changing to portrait/landscape

Tags: java, android, image, android-activity, imageview

I have an imageview with a bitmap picture on it. i set this picture in the onActivityResault. the problem is when i change to portrait/landscape the image disapears.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case 1:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                image.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use these line in AndroidManifest.xml in ur activity place. android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".it sloved my problem

Answer (score 4):

When orientation changes activity is destroyed and created again. If you're creating your layout using xml all widgets having @id set, should be automatically recreated with it's content. Otherwise you have to do that manually - take a look at Activity's methods `onRestoreInstanceState() onSaveInstanceState()` just override them and write your own save/restore code.
Some of untested code, hope, that it will give you an idea:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b){
    b.putParcelable("image", image.getBitmap());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle b){
    //you need to handle NullPionterException here.
    image.setBitmap((Bitmap) b.getParcelable("image"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain this a bit more?
I have a Bitmap object in my activity, how do i set the image view picture to that bitmap again on those methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you give an ID to your imageview it won't be disappear, when you change orientation. I think it's the easiest way, to keep, your view.

Answer (score 0):

Building off piotrpo's answer, here is a more specific version:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b){
    b.putParcelable("image", imageMap);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle b){
    imageMap = b.getParcelable("image");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageMap);
}
```

where `imageMap` is your bitmap image